# Is there an existing method to draw a heart of stars that looks more like a heart?

Tags: 2d

I wrote a C program [which prints a heartbeat (heart star) animation](https://github.com/albert10jp/c_learning/blob/main/heart_star_animation.c).

The key is to print a heart of stars, which looks like this

[image]

consists of line of stars and blanks.

```
    * * * *           * * * * 
  * * * * * *       * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * *   * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
  * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
    * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
      * * * * * * * * * * * 
        * * * * * * * * * 
          * * * * * * * 
            * * * * * 
              * * * 
                *
```

Is there an existing method to make it more like a heart? For example, how many lines should I use to draw the top half of the heart shape?

By "more like", I mean more roundish, like this

[image]

and this

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "more like a heart"? Can you give a drawing or an image or something of how you want it to look?

Comment: Google: Heart ascii graphics.

Comment: Related: https://youtu.be/aNR4n0i2ZlM